# How to call a bicep file from another repository?

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-bicep

I have a repository with bicep templates repo1. I have another repository(repo2) that need to use one of the bicep templates from the repo1.

In repo2 pipeline.yaml copies the bicep and param file to the artifacts directory and performs other build steps.

Then the stage yaml for release has a AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 task to deploy main.bicep.

The main bicep in repo2 should be calling the required bicep from repo1. I am struggling to achieve this.

yaml from repo2

```
parameters:

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: IaC
    type: git
    name: BicepTemplates

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    
name: 

variables: 
  
stages:
- stage: 
  jobs:
  - job: 
    workspace:
      clean: 
    pool:
      name:
      demands:
      
    steps:

    //multiple tasks       

- template: mystage.yaml
  parameters:
```

stage yaml

```
\\Ignore parameters, variables

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: ''
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 
    subscriptionId: 
    resourceGroupName: 
    location: 
    csmFile: 'main.bicep'
    csmParametersFile: 'mainbicep.parameters.json'
    deploymentMode:
```

main bicep

```
//parameters

//variables

module storageAccount '' = { //how to refer existing bicep file from repo1 as module
  name: ''
  params: {    
    
  }
}
```

In main bicep how can I refer the existing storage account bicep from repo1?

Comment: You have to `checkout` the additional repository and then it's just a matter of ensuring the path to the module is correct.

Comment: I have tried this before and followed a few github threads and at that point there was nothing. I had to create azure container registry. But now I have two tenants where I need bicep modules to be published and used which is making things very complex.

Comment: Daniel Mann - I am checking out the repo as shown in my question (yaml from repo2) But post that I am not able to find a way to refer files from that in main.bicep

Comment: Once you have both repos checked out, you just need to figure out the correct relative path to use. This is something you'll need to determine yourself by looking at the directory structure on disk after you checked out the repos. So something like `../other_repo/whatever/foo.bicep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [checkout step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) and set the path. Then in your main.bicep you can navigate to it with a relative path.

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: IaC
    type: git
    name: BicepTemplates

steps:
- checkout: self
  path: MyProject
- checkout: IaC
  path: IaC_Libary
- script: |
    az deployment group create -g myRg -f ../MyProject/sampleproject/main.bicep
```

/sampleproject/main.bicep file

```
module storageAccount '../../IaC_Libary/bicep/modules/storage.bicep' = {
  name: ''
  params: {    
    
  }
}
```

Working sample pipeline in a public AzDo project; https://gordonbyers.visualstudio.com/_git/IaC?path=/azure-pipelines.yml

---

Another option is to use [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (I think this would be my preference).

In your repo, you can add the IaC repo as a submodule using the `git submodule add` command.

Then in a single Pipeline `checkout` step you can specify `submodules: recursive` which will fetch both repositories. This makes the authoring easier as when you're working on the repo locally the relative file structure will be identical to when it's running in Azure DevOps.

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: recursive
- script: |
    ls
    ls myproject
  name: debug 
- script: |
    bicep build myproject/main.bicep
  displayName: 'bicep build'
```

Working sample pipeline in a public AzDo project; https://gordonbyers.visualstudio.com/IaC/_git/Iac-Submodules?path=/azure-pipelines.yml
I've even documented the submodule piece [here](https://gordonbyers.visualstudio.com/IaC/_git/Iac-Submodules?path=/README.md&_a=preview) too.

Comment: If my repo where I am checking out the IaC is having a structure as one yaml which calls stage yaml and stage yaml has my main bicep deployment call. Main bicep is in another folder referring the modules from checked out repo. In this case my checkout step will be in main yaml file right?

Comment: As shown in my question, the repo where I am checking out IaC(Bicep template repo). In main yaml I have - steps: 
-chcekout: self
- checkout: IaC
  path: IaC_Libary
- task: AzureCli@2
  inputs:
 azureSubscription:
 scriptType:
 scriptLocation:
 inlineScript: 'az bicep buils --file MyApp/Azure/main.bicep'
 
//other tasks

//call stage yaml

stage.yaml
//Call AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 with main bicep as csmfile

main.bicep is referring bicep files in other repo

Comment: If I did like above I am getting the following error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\agents\build2\_work\46\s\MyApp\Azure\main.bicep'

Comment: You'll need checkout steps repeated in each stage, different stages can run on different agents

Comment: I used CmdLine@2 to figure out what is happening. So here is the situation: checkout self is going to s\MyApp and check out template repo is going to IaC_Library. If I do a DIR I get MyApp as one of the directory under which I have main bicep now my main bicep has to refer IaC_Library so I have module mod '../IaC_Library/MyTemplates/storage.bicep' = { } . I did a cd.. in cmdline task which gave C:\_agents\build2\_work\46 and then a DIR on it lists IaC_Library as one of the directories

Comment: Referring the way I showed I am getting the following error: Could not find a part of the path C:\_agents\build2\_work\46\s\MyApp\MyFolder\IaC_Library\MyTemplates\storage.bicep It should be referring C:\_agents\build2\_work\46\IaC_Library\MyTemplates\storage.bicep

Comment: I'm guessing you've fixed this then?  I've created a pipeline of my own that references all the paths over multiple repos. I still think my preference would be to use Git submodules tho :)   https://gordonbyers.visualstudio.com/_git/IaC?path=/azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: I have a small question still on checkout step. - checkout: BicepTemplate
      path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/iac_library // I am getting an error ##[error]C:\_agents\build2\_work\46\iac_library can not be a rooted path. As of now my repo that refers the bicep template from checked out repo is in C:\_agents\build2\_work\46\s\ and the iac_library folder (which has templates) is checked out in C:\_agents\build2\_work\46 (If I just write path: iac_library)

Comment: My main bicep file in the repo is much inside and then to refer I have to come a lot of levels up to refer iac_library like: module mod '../../../../../iac_library/Biceptemplates/mystorageaccount.bicep' . How do I force checkout to happen in a particular directory? And if it is possible to checkout just one folder if required from the repository?

Comment: I don't think you can checkout one folder...  But once you've checked the repo out, you could always run a command to move the single subdirectory you want to a better location.